# Why the data doesn't want to be appear in my .json file using nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

1.) I have a function that **successfully generates random words** in accordance with the user input (**if user input is 10 than 10 random words will be displayed on the website**). A have a json server were I'm getting the words using GET request fetch api as you can see below:

```
function getRandomWords() {
    let words = getServerData('http://localhost:3000/words').then(data => {
        const wordsToMemorize = document.querySelector('#words-to-memorize');
        document.querySelector("#wordsInput").addEventListener("click", function() {
            let temp = wordsToMemorize.value;
            generatedArrayELements.innerHTML = "";
            for(let i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
            let rander = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000);
            generatedArrayELements.innerHTML += data[rander] + "</br>";
        }})
});
}
```

2.) I want to transfer the generated words to my .json file in to the `randomwords array` but it doesn't want to work. And using DOM down there also doesnt make sense that I just realised:

```
    function putServerData() {
    let data = getRandomWords();
let fetchOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
};

return fetch("http://localhost:3000/randomwords", fetchOptions)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));

}

document.querySelector("#wordsInput").addEventListener("click", function() { 
    putServerData();
})
```

3.) I feel like being very close to my goal because the random word generator works and I can also POST data in to the .json file if I set manually the value to the `let data` variable, like `let data = ["test"]`. **What I dont know is how to send the generated random words in to my .json file.**

4.) My json file:

```
{
  "randomwords": [],
  "words": [
    "a",
    "abandon",
    "ability",
    "able",
    "abortion",
    "about",
    "above",
    "abroad",
    "absence",
    "absolute",
    "absolutely",
    "absorb",
    "abuse",
    "academic",
    "accept",
    "access"...(remaining words...)
}]
```

4.) I tried to follow the documentation. Maybe I need to use some `timeout` because the random words first need to be generated before I use `POST request` on them. I've been struggling with this for almost a week and cant find solution, I read almost every relating post in SO. Every help would be greatly appreciated.

return a promise in my **getRandomWords()** with some `timeout` can be a working solution?

Comment: Your function does not `return` any data. `let data = getRandomWords();`. what are you getting here ?

Comment: I edited the post. I expected getting the random words in here: `let data = getRandomWords();` but it isnt working because at that point the words are not generated yet, right? I was just trying something there. I can grab the random words with this: `let temp = document.querySelector("output");
let temp2 = temp.value;
console.log(temp2);`

Comment: Do you have any idea @xMayank how to POST my random generated words using the `putServerData` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add date to json file by making a `fetch` `post` call, however what you can do is write the data to your json file, you can do that by using the node `fs` `module`.
first make a route handler

```
const fs = require('fs')
router.post("/savedata", (req, res) => {
  const jsondata = req.body
  fs.writeFileSync('./path/to/your/json/data', jsondata, err => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("error saving file")
    } else {
      res.send("data saved successfully")
    }
  })
})
```

and then use fetch to make a call to your passing the data in the body

Comment: Hey @Sven.hig! Thanks for the advice. So how will the words generated by `getRandomWords()` get into the json file? I have `output` element in the html file where the words appear after the user click on the button: `let data = document.querySelector("output");`

Comment: you can use the same post route to send a response from the `json` file after it is updated you just change the line for `res,send(msg)` and you put  anything you need

Comment: or make a separate get route handler to serve the data

Comment: I need to read the documentation about it. I'm getting an error with `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`, however both `fs` and `browserify` are installed.

Comment: the code above should be in your `node js` serve which supports `common js` syntax however you can try and use this as an alternative  [fs for browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs)

Comment: My code is in my nodeJS server, using vsc. My package.json is: 
  `"name": "words",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "engwords.json",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browserify-fs": "^1.0.0",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "uniq": "^1.0.1"
  }
}`

Comment: so you can't use `require` on node?strange

Comment: I was thinking and what if I stick to my code I was using above with the different that my getRandomWords() would return a promise when the words are generated? Does that make any sense?